# How to group by multiple columns faster than lapply in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to apply a function to multiple columns and then aggregate those columns. I know I can do it using `lapply` as below.

```
DT1 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x*C - x*exp(num)/sum(exp(num)))),by =.(A, B), .SDcols = c("col1", "col2")]
```

Is there a faster way to do it using `set` or some other function?

**EDIT:**

Upon further investigation, I found that the `lapply` is the bottleneck. So basically the question can be simplified to as below.

Is there a faster way to calculate following?

```
DT1 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum),by =.(A, B), .SDcols = c("col1", "col2")]
```